# Win Srv 2012 task scheduler - trigger based on domain workstation logon/logoff/sleep/wake

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scheduler, task

I've got a domain controller (only one) with Win Srv 2012 and a number of workstations with Win 7. I need to run a task on a DC straight after domain user logon/off/sleep/wake to a workstation. The script is a powershell script that inserts data into SQL - data is to be used as a work time report.

What trigger should I use to get that?

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: Can the trigger be initiated by the workstation, or may it absolutely happen on the DC?

Comment: Needs to be DC. The task runs powershell script that inserts data to an SQL table - when it is initiated by workstation insert not always work (SQL connection etc.)

Comment: 1) Is there only one DC or are there multiple? 2) Must the action that inserts the data into the SQL database occur real-time after the user logs in, or is it OK if it happens some time later?

Comment: There's only one DC. Ideally the inserts happen straight after the logon but if not possible some delay will be acceptable. The whole thing is to register employees work time so apart from logon, also logoff, sleep and wake would need to be registered.

Comment: Ok, for starters you need to update your question with all of this information, it's all quite relevant.

Comment: Ok., I've updated the question.

Comment: Have you seen http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx ? Particularly *this method of user activity tracking is unreliable*. Logon, pull power cable, go home. No logoff/sleep/shutdown events logged.